# Convert templated parameter type to string

Tags: c++, templates

I've got a small bit of DRY going on in code I and others have written that I'd like to reduce but I'm failing to figure out how to get it done.  This is legacy COM code but it's interfering with the readability.  I'd like to do the following:

```
bool queryInterface<class T, class V>(T &_input, V &_output, Logger &_logger){
    if( FAILED( _input->QueryInterface( &_output ) ) ){
        _logger.error() << "Failed to Query Interface between " << MAGICHAPPENS<T>() 
                        << " and " << MAGICHAPPENS<V>();

        return false;
    }
    if( _output == NULL ){
        _logger.warn() << "Unable to Query Interface between " << MAGICHAPPENS<T>()
                       << " and " << MAGICHAPPENS<V>();

        return false;
    }
}
```

Wherein the "MAGICHAPPENS()" function would spit out the name of the variable type.  Such that if "V" were a `IQueryFilter` I'd get back a string of "IQueryFilter."  I can't think of any reasonable solution without having to write a bunch of template specializations totally defeating the point in the first place.

Is there a way to write ANDMAGICHAPPENS?

Comment: By the way, you could do: `if(FAILED(_input->QueryInterface(&_output)) || _output == NULL)` to not repeat the conditional code. Also, if `_input` and `_output` should be pointers, you should indicate that: `T* _input, V*& _output`. (Does `_input` need to be a reference?) Lastly, you're missing a `return true;`. :)

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are not using ATL? It already provides safe QI and tracing functionality.

Comment: They're _com_ptr_t smart pointer objects, typing out pass by reference is habit.  It's better for us to do `== NULL` separately because it lets us know when debugging if there was an issue with whatever version of the library they're using or if it was an actual failure.  But again, thanks.  I do appreciate it.

Comment: @gf Dunno.  What part of ATL you talking 'bout?  These objects are _com_prt_t< _comIIID<Foo,0x0> > objects (techincally a third-party API) and I'd love to learn about anything that could help sort things out.

Comment: For example when using ATL consistently `#define _ATL_DEBUG_QI` already provides QI tracing. I also find `CComQIPtr` invaluable. Hm, 3rd party though - i don't remember wether `CComPtr` et al traced that in a useful format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use RTTI to get the variable name:

```
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename T>
const char* type_name(void)
{
    // this, unfortunately, is implementation defined
    // and is allowed to be an empty string (useless!)
    return typeid(T).name(); 
}

_logger.error() << "Failed to Query Interface between " << type_name<T>() 
                    << " and " << type_name<V>();
```

Like the comments say, `name()` isn't guaranteed to be any particular formatting of the name, or any name at all. But it does require RTTI, which some people dislike.